# Nested filtering using CollectionViewSource in UserControl

Tags: wpf, collectionviewsource

I have a UserControl that displays some collection which should be filtered but the collection passed to the control might be filtered in the main window. It looks like this:

Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CollectionViewSourceTesting.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:CollectionViewSourceTesting="clr-namespace:CollectionViewSourceTesting"  
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Data}" x:Key="ItemsViewSource" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <CollectionViewSourceTesting:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsViewSource}}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="CollectionViewSourceTesting.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding}" x:Key="cvs" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is not working since CollectionViewSource.Source doesn't accept ListCollectionView, it throws an exception "'System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView' is not a valid value for property 'Source'.".

I figured I could use DataContextChanged event in UserControl to manually add filtering to the ListCollectionView but that would not be nesting and I would also need to set ListBox.ItemsSource property manually. I would use the existing view and change the Filter property. What I want to do is to create another view using CollectionViewSource so I could put in xaml. Is that possible?

I want my UserControl to handle normal collection as well as CollectionViews.

Comment: CollectionViewSource accepts only collections i.e. ListCollection, ObservableCollection etc. Can you please paste code where you have defined 'Data' property in your class??

Comment: Data is a simple ObservableCollection but thats not the point. the first CVS is fine, the problem is when I want to pass the View it created to the UserControl because inside I also have a CVS with filtering or sorting and I dont know whether the passed object is a simple collection or a view. As I've said it can be worked around in code behind but then I also need to set ItemsSource of the ListBox in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the same but it is something that is working for me.  I did it this way because I did not know filter was available for CollectionViewSource.  I use a trigger and viability. You could use a converter for some more advanced filter logic.  The user can can change the value for the trigger and the screen screen dynamically updates.  MyGabeLib.Search.SelectedDoc.DocFields is an ObservableCollection.

```
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="curDocFields"
        Source="{Binding Path=MyGabeLib.Search.SelectedDoc.DocFields}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="FieldDefApplied.AppliedDisplayOrder" Direction="Ascending"/>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="FieldDefApplied.FieldDef.DispName"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource> 

    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FieldDefApplied.AppliedDispDetail, Mode=OneWay}" Value="False" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
```

I found that if I change a value and want the sort to be refreshed I need:

```
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lbFields.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

Comment: I dont see any filtering in your code and you use a single CVS, I want to nest the view created by one CVS into another CVS as Source which is inside a UserControl that has no knowledge of the fact that it does get a view instead of a collection

Comment: As I said it may not be what you need.  If the Viability is Collapsed then it is virtually filtered.  But I agree it is not what you need.   I will delete my answer in a couple days.  Sorry.

Comment: @paparazzo: Call for action from the future :)